# Редактировать определённую категорию в woocommers

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть несколько категорий товаров, выведенных списком на странице. Одна из них Tips & Techniques. Её нужно оформить не как список товаров, а как текст с картинкой. Как мне получить доступ к этой категории?

Как я понимаю, через фильтр и хук я получаю доступ к ней, и правлю как хочу.
Что-то типа этого должно получится?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_page_title', [$this, 'custom_category_tips_techniques'] );
```